# Laravel class not found for mail

Tags: laravel, class, email, namespaces, laravel-mail

I'm trying to generate a notification email to the webmaster when there's a new registration on the site I'm building.

I have a mail class called SignedUp at App\Mail\SignedUp.php.

In the Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RegistersUser file, I have the following:

```
namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

use App\Organization;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use App\Mail\SignedUp;

trait RegistersUsers
{
    use RedirectsUsers;

    /**
     * Show the application registration form.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function showRegistrationForm()
    {
        $organizations = Organization::all();

        return view('auth.register', compact('organizations'));
    }

    /**
     * Handle a registration request for the application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function register(Request $request)
    {

        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

        event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

        $this->guard()->login($user);

        Mail::to('example@example.com')->send(new SignedUp($user));        

        return $this->registered($request, $user)
                        ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }
```

When I register a new user, I get this message:
**Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Mail' not found**

if I change `use App\Mail\SignedUp;` to `use App\Mail;`, the error is still: **Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Mail' not found**

`use Mail;` gives me **Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\SignedUp' not found**

`use App\Mail\SignedUp;` gives me **Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Mail' not found**

Not attempting to import the class at all, and instead changing my statement to: `\Mail::to('example@example.com')->send(new SignedUp($user));`, I get **Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\SignedUp' not found**

A cannot figure out how to get it to find my mail class.

I'm just guessing and shooting in the dark - can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my mail class file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class SignedUp extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $url = 'https://av-cuauhtemoc.org/users';

    public $user;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from('example@example.com')->view('emails.new-registration');
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add your mail class file here? i think there is a problem with your namespaces

Comment: @Zartosht Just added it.

Answer (score 2):

I finally stumbled upon the answer. 
I also needed to import the use `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;` class.

So this works:

```
use App\Mail\Signedup;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you shouldn't change `Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RegistersUser` file, instead you have to overwrite this method in your `RegisterController`:

```
use App\Mail\SignedUp;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Mail;

public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

        event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

        $this->guard()->login($user);

        Mail::to('example@example.com')->send(new SignedUp($user));

        return $this->registered($request, $user)
            ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }
```